# How to apply an domain on relational field odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Here is my `sale.order.line` module, I do some modifications 
[image]

I want to apply a domain on the product that not all product be displayed just products in Ligne contract field for example :

[image]

Here in my Contrat line, I Have just one Product so on the **Sale order** lines only this product (article) must be shown

Answer (score 3):

Use onchane event for this in your `sale.order.line`

```py
   @api.onchange('contrat_id')
   def set_domain(self):
         # force the user to reselect the producg if he changes the contrat line
         self.product_id = False
         if self.contrat_id :
                 return {'domain': {'product_id': [('id',  'in', self.contrat_id.product_ids.ids)]}}
         else: 
                 # remove the domain if no contrat is selected
                 return {'domain': {'product_id': []}}
```

I'm using my phone sorry if i made a syntax error but I hope you get the idea

**Edits**

Okay in your contract model you don't have a many2many field to product model as I thought instead you have this one2many field `ligne contract`

So let suppose that the name of that field is `ligne_ids` in this `one2many` relation there is a `many2one` field to product model let us say its name is `product_id`.

Use the power of mapped to extract in one line all product ids in the contract lignes.

```py
       #     many2one ->   one2many       -> mapped('many2one') this will collect of the records without duplication from the o2m field.
       #     contract ->  contract lignes -> products
   self.contrat_lignes_id.ligne_ids.mapped('product_id').ids
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you a lot I adapted the function, but I don't know where is the problem it doesn't work for can you look to the comment @EasyOdoo

Comment: Okay check my edits this what you need exactly tell me if you didn't understand some thing. and remove your answer and just edit you question to provide more details like I just did it's better